# How to print specific value from line in a file

Tags: parsing, return-value, println

I have created a search that will find data in a file. The data that gets printed contains a value that I would like to be shown instead of the whole line.

With the below code, I search for `OMXS303F;` and get this as result:
`BDt;i4244190;Si26944;s6;Ex4206868;Mk4206874;INiFXS30;SYmOMXS303F;ISnSE0016998389;CUtSEK;PRt1;VOd1;Cf1;TTd20230616;CFcFFICSX;ITSz4206882;NDp6;MPmN;MPaN;NDTp6;ITStN;STy2;AUmY;LSz1;`
This is what I would like to have as a result instead:
`i4244190`

All help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileReadContent {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Enter date YYYY-MM-DD: ");
        Scanner dateInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String date = dateInput.next();
        Path pathFileToRead = Paths.get("c:\\tmp\\data-full-"+date+".tip");
        
        System.out.println("Enter symbol: ");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String symbol = reader.readLine();
        
        Files.lines(pathFileToRead)
            .filter(str -> str.contains(symbol))
            .forEach(System.out::println);

        dateInput.close();
        reader.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see how you expect that output. Your code always prints lines, it does not try to find fields in those lines. Your file format looks like csv, so you could look for a csv parsing library and use that. Or find the stuff you want to print manually, either by knowing at which position in the line it starts and ends, or by looking for the `;` and treating that as a field separator, then picking the 2nd field, instead just printing each matching line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did solve the issue:

```
    StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Files.lines(pathFileToRead)
        .filter(str -> str.contains(symbol))
        .forEach(s -> contentBuilder.append(s).append("\n"));
    String fileContent = contentBuilder.toString(); 

    String r = ";i.*?(?=;)+;";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(r);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(fileContent);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
```